# Hash operations in array of the hashes - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, hash

I have an array with having following elements:

```
$scope.users = [{"id": "1", "name": "Jai Rajput"}, {"id":"2", "name": "Nakul Sharma"}, {"id": "3", "Name": "Lovey Rajput"}]
```

Now I want to perform an `update` and `delete` in the shortest way on this `Array`.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried by yourself?

Comment: Looks like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both operations can be made with `Array#find` function.

```js
let $scope = {};
$scope.users = [{"id": "1", "name": "Jai Rajput"}, {"id":"2", "name": "Nakul Sharma"}, {"id": "3", "Name": "Lovey Rajput"}];

$scope.users.find(v => v.id == 1).name = "Jai Kumar Rajput";
$scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf($scope.users.find(v => v.id == 3)), 1);

console.log($scope.users);
```